# Laravel 5.6 + JWT (json web token)

Tags: jwt, laravel-5.6

Boa tarde a todos,

Estou desenvolvendo uma API em Laravel e pretendo utilizar o JWT(Json web Token) para realizar a autenticação e gerenciamento dos tokens.

Li a documentação no GITHUB, porem não entendi qual seria a sua versão mais recente e estável para o LARAVEL 5.6.

Sei que por padrão o JWT utiliza a Model USER para realizar o gerenciamento, porem preciso criar uma MODEL customizada, sei que na versão 0.5.12 do JWT( sem suporte ao laravel 5.6) havia uma opção para habilitar a Model desejada. Hoje verifiquei que na versão DEVELOP não existe mais a opção para definir a MODEL em si, seria possível customizar?

Referencias:
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Answer (score 0):

Sendo sincero nessa nova versão eu não sei se isso daria certo, mas não custa tentar ¯/*(ツ)*/¯

```
Config::set('jwt.user', seuModel::classe);
```